# About mongodb 3.0.2 auth

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I upgraded my mongodb server to version v3.0.2.
Everything seems to be working fine except for auth user creation, the documentation about this version states, that it works the same as the previous versions: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser
But for some reason it doesn't seem to be working for me:

```js
root@Bakalaurs:~# mongo
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.addUser({user:"root", pwd:"asd", roles:[ "userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWrite" ] } )
2015-05-01T06:14:07.029-0400 E QUERY    TypeError: Property 'addUser' of object admin is not a function
    at (shell):1:4
> use bakalaurs
switched to db bakalaurs
> db.addUser({user:"bakalaurs", pwd:"asdf", roles:[ "readWrite" ]})
2015-05-01T06:15:36.595-0400 E QUERY    TypeError: Property 'addUser' of object bakalaurs is not a function
    at (shell):1:4
bye
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: nevermind, just noticed that now it's createUser instead of addUser, changed the function and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

`addUser` has been deprecated since version 2.6:. You need use db.createUser() and db.updateUser() instead of db.addUser() to add users to MongoDB, see:

http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.addUser/

The above link is redirected to `db.createUser()`. You can find more details regarding `db.updateUser` here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.updateUser/

Answer (score 0):

```
db.addUser(<user document>)
```

Deprecated since version 2.6: Use db.createUser() and db.updateUser() instead of db.addUser() to add users to MongoDB.